# PDO PHP Stored Procedure (bindParam)

Tags: php, pdo

Everything worked for me with bindParam and PDO.
But the moment I add 3 bindParam, it doesn't work.

Example that work:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("select * from SP_IMPORT_CRM_SELECTIE(?,?,'test','org naam','French','1','2','adres','adres1','city','city','state','state','postal','postal','country','country','po','po','phone','other','email','otheremail','fax','web','VAT')");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $firma, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ACC, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
```

The moment I add a third param, my browser gives me the message = Can't receive data:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("select * from SP_IMPORT_CRM_SELECTIE(?,?,?,'org naam','French','1','2','adres','adres1','city','city','state','state','postal','postal','country','country','po','po','phone','other','email','otheremail','fax','web','VAT')");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $firma, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ACC, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $org, PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
```

Is there a limit on bindParam?

Comment: Maybe there is a limit but for sure not 3. Where is the `$org` come from?

Comment: I defined three parameters on top of the file .. $firma=11;
$ACC="AC123456789";
$org="orgnaam";

Comment: Its hard to give a hint with only an error message like `Can't receive data`

Comment: Your SQL statement makes no sence!

Comment: Oh wow, I havent even noted that..

Comment: Why is that? It works without parameters? So I think the SQL is correct?

Comment: I executed the SQL query on my Database, and it works? select * from SP_IMPORT_CRM_SELECTIE(11,'test','test','org naam','French','1','2','adres','adres1','city','city','state','state','postal','postal','country','country','po','po','phone','other','email','otheremail','fax','web','VAT')

Answer (score 0):

I have 26 input parameters. When I return 26 values in my stored procedure, IT WORKS..
It that normal?
So you always have to have the same number of input as output parameter?